# How do I fix the Ubuntu Installer not detecting my hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu

I've been trying to switch to Ubuntu for a while now. I'm able to boot into an Ubuntu Live session with UNetBootin and everything detects my hard drive except for the installer. My hard drive has elementaryOS 5.0 Hera installed on it, and I don't know how to run it as superuser so I could delete the partition. Can anyone help? It'd be appreciated. Also my PC uses Legacy.

Comment: Cause 1: the elementary partition is hibernated or not shut down properly. Cause 2: The bootable usb is not correctly configured. If you have access to a live usb you can install gparted with `sudo apt install gparted` and delete or modify any partition.

Comment: I'm not using a bootable USB. I selected Hard Drive in UNetBootin. Should I use a bootable USB for this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to install directly from the hard drive so I'd suggest using a bootable USB

Comment: Alright, I'll test a bootable USB -- I'll be back later.